# Formula for exponential map of two noncommuting matrix sum

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am interested in finding some formula to compute $e^{X+Y},$ if $[X, Y]\neq 0.$ I would like to have something like $e^{X+Y}=e^X\cdot e^Y \cdot e^{F(X, Y)}.$ Also, I have some constrains on commutation relations between $X, Y$
$$[Y,[X,[X,Y]]]=0,$$
$$[X,[Y,[Y,X]]]=0.$$
I know about BCH formula, which is $e^X\cdot e^Y=e^{Z(X, Y)},$ but it is the opposite of what I need.

Comment: The dual of the BKH formula is sometimes called Zassenhaus formula. You can find it on Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Comment: @lcv you mean BCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the explicit computation of the Zassenhaus formula see for example this [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0389.pdf). So we have
$$
e^{X+Y}=e^Xe^Ye^{Z_2(X,Y)}e^{Z_3(X,Y)}\cdots, 
$$
where
\begin{align*}
Z_2(X,Y) & = -\frac{1}{2}[X,Y],\\
Z_3(X,Y) & = \frac{1}{3}[Y,[X,Y]] + \frac{1}{6}[X,[X,Y]]\\
Z_4(X,Y) & = -\frac{1}{8}[Y,[Y,[X,Y]] - \frac{1}{8}[Y,[X,[X,Y]]-\frac{1}{24}[X,[X,[X,Y]]]\\
\cdots & = \cdots
\end{align*}
Because of your assumptions the formula becomes easier.